# How can I implement my own method when instantiating an interface?

Tags: java, methods, interface, instantiation

I have an interface:

```
public interface ExampleInterface {

  public void exampleMethod();

  public void anotherExampleMethod();

}
```

And an example class:

```
public class ExampleClass implements ExampleInterface{


  public ExampleClass() {
    ........
  }

  public void exampleMethod() {
    ..............
  }

  public void anotherExampleMethod() {
    ..............
  }


  public void myOwnMethod() {
    ........
  }

}
```

I instantiate the class by using the interface like so:

```
ExampleInterface exampleClass = new ExampleClass();
```

Doing this is ok:

```
exampleClass.exampleMethod();
```

But this is not:

```
exampleClass.myOwnMethod();
```

However, this works:

```
ExampleClass exampleClass = new ExampleClass();
exampleClass.myOwnMethod();
```

Why is it when I instantiate with an interface and try to call a method that is not part of the interface it doesn't work? Is there anyway to call `myOWnMethod()` while still instantiating with the interface?

Comment: Read up on declared/static type vs runtime/dynamic type. And how method invocations are resolved.

Comment: The answer is in the question: the method is not part of the interface, so you can't call it, since the compiler has no way to know that this method is available on the object.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a reference variable of type `ExampleInterface`, there is no knowledge that it's really an `ExampleClass`, so there is no guarantee that there is a `myOwnMethod` to call.  You can create another class, `SillyExampleClass` that implements `ExampleInterface`, but you don't define a `myOwnMethod` method there.  That's why you can't call `myOwnMethod`, it may not be there on the actual implementation.

If you want to call `myOwnMethod()` on a reference variable of the `ExampleInterface` interface, then you include `myOwnMethod` in the interface definition, because the interface definition specifies what must be in any implementation of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have an interface `Person` and then you implement it in two classes: `Boy` and `Girl`. If you have the method `bePregnant()` in the `Girl` class, when you do:

```
Person person = new Boy();
```

calling `bePregnant()` method in that object won't make sense. However, there is one way to check if the person is a `Girl` before you call some method that doesn't belong to `Person` interface:

```
if (person instanceof Girl)
    ((Girl) person).bePregnant();
```

First, `instanceof` is used to check wheter an object is an instance of another class (this class can be also a superclass of the object). Then what (SomeClass) object does, is called **casting**. In your case you could do this:

```
ExampleInterface exampleClass = new ExampleClass();
((ExampleClass) exampleClass).myOwnMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

In both examples you create an instance of ExampleClass. But in the first one you reference it with a variable of type ExampleInterface (which has no method myOwnMethod) in the second example you reference it with a variable of type ExampleClass (which do has a method myOwnMethod)!
If you want to call myOwnMethod on your ExampleInterface you could cast it to ExampleClass.

```
((ExampleClass) exampleInterface).myOwnMethod()
```

this is not save if you are not sure that the object which exampleInterface is referring to is actually of type ExampleClass. Otherwise you'll get a ClassCastException.